# Smarty output filters with Codeigniter and Ci-Smarty "not callable" error

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, codeigniter-2, smarty3

Im currently using codeigniter 2 with ci-Smarty. Just been trying to add a smarty output filter but not having much luck. Its as if the function cannot be found or something?

I am using a plugin as the output filter function and have the following code:

**LOCATION:** /libraries/Smarty.php

```
// Set email output filter
$this->loadFilter('output', 'protect_email');
```

**LOCATION:** /third_party/Smarty/plugins/function.protect_email.php

```
function smarty_function_protect_email($tpl_output, Smarty_Internal_Template $template)
{
    $tpl_output =
       preg_replace('!(\S+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3}))!',
                    '$1%40$2', $tpl_output);
    return $tpl_output;
}
```

The above seems to throw the following smarty error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message
>   'outputfilter "protect_email" not callable' in
>   /home/something/public_html/application/third_party/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:717
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/something/public_html/application/libraries/Smarty.php(46):
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->loadFilter('output', 'protect_email') #1
>   /home/something/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(1095):
>   CI_Smarty->__construct(Array) #2
>   /home/something/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(975):
>   CI_Loader->_ci_init_class('Smarty', '', NULL, NULL) #3
>   /home/something/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(216):
>   CI_Loader->_ci_load_class('smarty', NULL, NULL) #4
>   /home/something/public_html/application/libraries/MY_Parser.php(29):
>   CI_Loader->library('smarty') #5
>   /home/something/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(1099):
>   MY_Parser->__construct() #6
>   /home/something/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(938):
>   CI_Loader->_ci_init_class('Parser', 'MY_', NULL, NULL) #7
>   /home/something/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(216): CI_Loa in
>   /home/something/public_html/application/third_party/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   on line 717

Sorry about it being so long! Just thought seeing the whole error may help.

Thanks a lot for reading and hope someone can help.

-->EDIT
Also just tried to explicitly set the plugins directory location using:

```
$this->setPluginsDir(config_item('plugin_directory'));
```

The echoed out the location which is correct but still get the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay that was a silly mistake.

For anyone else who has the same problem I was just looking through and realised the plugin should not be referred to as a regular function. For example it should have been called:

```
outputfilter.protect_email.php
```

Also make the same amends with the function name as well so in my case it should be called:

```
smarty_outputfilter_protect_email
```

This worked great for me.